# For polynomial systems, is it possible to compute the multiplier of a periodic point without a direct formula for every iteration of the function?

Tags: polynomials, dynamical-systems

I ask this in direct reference to the following problem:

> Consider the polynomial $C:[-1,1]→[-1,1]$ defined by $C(x):=4x^3-3x$. Prove that for every integer $n \ge 2$, the multiplier of every periodic point of minimal period $n$ of $C$ is equal to $3^n$ or $-3^n$. Furthermore, prove that both cases occur.

My first thought was to try and derive a formula for $C^n$ (as finding a formula for a linear mapping was fairly easy), but trying to iterate more than once is so painstaking, I'm not sure it's even possible.

I've looked at the multiplier formula: 
$$(C^n)'(x_0)=C'(C^{n-1}(x_0))C'(C^{n-2}(x_0)) \cdots C'(C(x_0))C'(x_0)$$
where $x_0$ is a periodic point of minimal period $n$, and considered that perhaps somehow the average of each term in the product is $3$ or $-3$, so that the total product is $3^n$ if there are an even number of negative terms and $-3^n$ if odd?

If this is viable, I have no idea how to go about it, as this gives a clean answer, but the only way I know how to compute multipliers is directly with an explicit formula for each $C^i$. Is it possible to compute such a formula in this case, or is there another method I should be using to look at this problem?